# name 'DOUBLE_PRECISION' is not defined - PostgreSQL - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am running a migrate script in postgres, and at the top of one of the files I have `from sqlalchemy import *`

in the file I create tables with entries such as

`1Column('tmp1', DOUBLE_PRECISION(precision=53))`

However, when I run the script I get the error:

`name 'DOUBLE_PRECISION' is not defined`

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd advise against doing 'from  import *' that can bring unknown things into your namespace that are quite difficult to debug.

Second, the sqlalchemy module simply doesn't have a 'DOUBLE_PRECISION' column type. So the reason it says it's not defined, is because sqlalchemy does not define any such name. Perhaps you are looking for 'Float'?